# Azure mobile service doesn't register push notifications tags on Android

Tags: azure-mobile-services, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to use the following code to send push notifications to specific users with tags (VS Cordova Project using Azure mobile service).

```
            var tags = [userid, platform];
            // Get the handle returned during registration. 
            var handle = data.registrationId;
            // Set the device-specific message template. 
            if (platform == "android" || platform == "Android") {
                // Template registration. 
                var template = '{ "data" : {"message":"$(message)"}}';
                // Register for notifications. 
                mobileServiceClient.push.gcm.registerTemplate(handle,
                    "myTemplate", template, null, tags)
                    .done(registrationSuccess, registrationFailure);
            } else if (platform == "iOS") {

                // Template registration. 
                var template = '{"aps": {"alert": "$(message)"}}';

                // Register for notifications.             
                mobileServiceClient.push.apns.registerTemplate(handle,
                    "myTemplate", template, null, tags)
                    .done(registrationSuccess, registrationFailure);
            }
```

It registered successfully with the tags for Apple APNS , however on android it only registered the device, but the tags doesn't get registered.

[image]

I'm using push plugin 1.4.4 and Azure mobile service 1.2.9

Does anyone knows how to fix this? Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After tracing the source code of azure mobile service plugin, I found that

```
gcm.prototype.registerTemplate = function (deviceId, name, bodyTemplate, tags)
```

is missing the "expiryTemplate" parameter. Changing it to

```
gcm.prototype.registerTemplate = function (deviceId, name, bodyTemplate, expiryTemplate, tags)
```

fix the problem.

Comment: registerTemplate, just passes null by default to the internal register for expiry, return this._push._registerTemplate('gcm', deviceId, name, bodyTemplate, null, tags);  https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Javascript/src/Push/Push.Web.js#L261

Why update register to take the expiry

Answer (score 0):

My blog [here](http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2016/08/azure-custom-function-bindings-notification-tags-in-cordova-apps/) details on how to receive notifications based on tags in a Cordova client. Basically you'll need a bit of server side code to update your installation / registration to handle specific tags. That's this bit of code:

```
NotificationHubClient _hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(notificationHubConnection, notificationHubName);

public async Task CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(string installationId, string registrationId, IEnumerable<string> tags)
{
    Installation installation = new Installation();
    installation.InstallationId = installationId;
    installation.PushChannel = registrationId;
    installation.Tags = tags.ToArray();
    installation.Platform = NotificationPlatform.Gcm;

    await _hub.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);
}
```